# Kio estas la diferenco de la verboj "porti" kaj "surhavi"?

Tags: word-difference, akademia-vortaro

Saluton. Mi priserĉis la signifojn de tiuj ĉi du verboj, sed ŝajnas al mi ke ili estas tutsamaj kaj tutegalaj. Ĉu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mallonge por la demandinto:

La verbo `porti` ankaŭ signifas `porti sur si` do normale oni povas senzorge pritrakti ilin kiel sinonimojn, **se temas pri vestaĵoj**.

Pli detale, en aliaj okazoj:

`Surhavi` estas io fakta, ne nepre longdaŭra, kiu povas okazi kun aŭ sen partopreno de la surhavanto. `Porti` povas subkomprenigi penon, daŭron volon, movon... Ekzemple:

```
Jesuo portis krucon
Jesuo surhavis krucon (la signifo estas tute alia)
```

Eĉ ĉe vestaĵoj tiu nuanco povas malhelpeti tujan komprenon:

```
1. Li surhavas pezan vintran jakon
2. Li portas pezan vintran jakon
```

En la dua frazo oni ne certas ĉu temas pri subteno (li portas ĝin al la lavmaŝino aŭ al la ŝranko) aŭ pri surhavo (li havas sur si ĉar malvarmegas).

Comment: Jes, ne estas tiom simpla. Verŝajne pro denaska lingva influo mi ĉiam asocias "porti" kun "porti en mano". Ofte mi asocias "surhavi" kun "nia domo surhavas tegmenton", tute ne kun vestaĵoj. Tial mi devigis min mem parkerigi, ke "surhavi" ankaŭ signifas "surhavi iu vestaĵon".

Comment: Dankegon pro via instrua respondo, Sinjor' Trápani.