# What is the difference between "portas" and "surhavas"?

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between *portas* and *surhavas*, which were both given as translation for *is wearing* from Duolingo?

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! The same question has already been asked (and answered) in Esperanto: [Kio estas la diferenco de la verboj “porti” kaj “surhavi”?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/5880/1576)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kio estas la diferenco de la verboj "porti" kaj "surhavi"?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/kio-estas-la-diferenco-de-la-verboj-porti-kaj-surhavi)

Answer (score 2):

*Porti* is used in Esperanto in a similar way to the German verb "tragen", which can be translated in different ways into English depending on the context. All in all [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#porti_kd) gives five definitions for the verb, one of which is "to have something on oneself or with oneself", especially "to wear a piece of clothing".

- *Mi portas silkajn ŝtrumpojn kaj mufon.* (Z)
- *Mi portas somerajn vestojn.*

[*Surhavi*](https://vortaro.net/#surhavi_kd) is limited to *porti 3*.

- *La koverto surhavis multajn poŝtmarkojn.*
- *surhavi ĉapelon, veston*

When it comes to wearing a cloth, the verbs are interchangeable. If you want to see a difference, all I can think of is a headdress. For me *surhavi ĉapelon* is more logical than *porti ĉapelon*.

Having said that I would like to make a remark conserning footwear. In some languages the logic goes that while you can have pieces of clothing on you, footwear is something you are on. For those people *porti ŝuon* gets associated with carring a shoe in your hand and *surhavi ŝuon* with having a shoe on your head or something other odd. They are likely to use *teni ŝuon (je la piedo)* (see [*teni 1*](https://vortaro.net/#teni_kd)) or some other verb.